# lmax RingBuffer with log4j takes up a lot of memory

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, tomcat9

I'm running a Tomcat web application in debug mode and, looking through the biggest objects with YourKit profiler, I see that by far the largest is a single instance of `com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer`. I assume this has something with log4j, which uses `RingBuffer` internally to report asynchronously. Is there any way I can reduce the memory footprint of this object? Why is it so large?

Comment: How large is it? What's the Tomcat version?

Comment: 42M, running on Tomcat 9 with Java 8.

Comment: Is 42M really a problem?

Comment: Not a problem, but I was curious about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Async Log4j2, memory leak?](https://frandorado.github.io/spring/2019/05/30/async-log4j2-memory-leak.html#why):

> The implementation of Apache Log4j2 in async mode uses a RingBuffer to
>   buffering all the logs content. By default uses 262144 slots (256 *
>   1024). This causes an initial memory reserve of approximately 40
>   megabytes and in a environment with a limited memory causes the memory
>   head to be always full and therefore the starting slowdown.

To reduce the memory usage, reduce the RingBuffer size (number of slots) by setting the system property:

```
log4j2.asyncLoggerRingBufferSize=value
```

The minimum size is 128. To allocate 5Mb set the value to 32768. See [Log4j Async Loggers](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html) for more information.